# How to stop babel from prefixing "_" for methodnames containing same name as javascript keywords

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am transforming a class from es6 to es5 using babel transpiler.
This is the sample class.

```
class TestClass{
 switch(){ 
 }
 getState(){

 }
}
```

This gets transformed as

```
 var TestClass = function () {
  function TestClass() {
    _classCallCheck(this, TestClass);
     }

    _createClass(TestClass, [{
       key: "switch",
       value: function _switch() {}
    }, {
       key: "getState",
       value: function getState() {}
    }]);

    return TestClass;
 }();
```

If you notice here, switch method is automatically prefixed with "_" by babel. How to avoid this?

Here is the babel transformation [demo](https://es6console.com/jonz1n41/)

Comment: What do you expect the transpiler to do, if you used a reserved word? Creating invalid JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't test it first. There is nothing wrong with Babel. The `_switch()` is naught but an internal unexposed method that Babel creates during transpile (something you shouldn't really care about). Your accessible method is still called `.switch()` as all things should be.

```
class TestClass{
 switch(){
   return "foo"
 }
 getState(){

 }
}

console.log(new TestClass().switch()) //foo
console.log(new TestClass()._switch()) //undefined
```

```js
"use strict";

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var TestClass = function () {
  function TestClass() {
    _classCallCheck(this, TestClass);
  }

  _createClass(TestClass, [{
    key: "switch",
    value: function _switch() {
      return "foo";
    }
  }, {
    key: "getState",
    value: function getState() {}
  }]);

  return TestClass;
}();

console.log(new TestClass().switch())
```